# actionscript 3.0 writing all array data into text file

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, text

I've a problem about getting all array data and wrting them into a text file. For example I have an array names[] and it includes A, B, C. I tried this code:

```
for (i:uint=0; i<file.length; i++)
{
        file = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("allnames.txt");
        var fileStream = new FileStream;
        fileStream.open (file,FileMode.WRITE);
        fileStream.writeUTFBytes (names[i]+"\r\n");
        fileStream.close ();
}
```

But as result, it's always writing the last data, C for three times. What i want is to write A, B and C line by line. Thanks.

Comment: I doubt your code -as is- compiles as the 'File' class doesn't have a 'length' property (1st: replace with 'names.length' in the loop dec.). In this case you are opening the file "allnames.txt" writing to it than closing it 3 times. Move all that precedes 'writeUTFBytes' above the loop then close the stream after the loop ends. Also, in cases where you need to add data to a file use 'FileMode.APPEND' instead of 'WRITE'.

Comment: Ok. I just needed to delete and create text file again. What you said has worked Chadyk. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible that you mean this code, it's working properly

```
var names: Array = ["word1", "word2", "word3"];
var file: File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("allnames.txt");
var fileStream: FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open (file,FileMode.WRITE);

for (var i:uint=0; i<names.length; i++)
{
    fileStream.writeUTFBytes (names[i]+"\r\n");
}
fileStream.close ();
```

Comment: When I try these codes, it's not working. Instead of writing new lines, program keeps writing the last line as much as length of names. APPEND on the other hand is the correct code for writing all lines.

Comment: Yes, I used those codes before you suggest me :) Thanks for help anyway